# Aspect ratio constraint relative to the screen width

Tags: ios, swift3, uiimageview, nslayoutconstraint

I have set a cell image to my `UITableViewCell`. It is a custom cell. I have set the aspect ratio as 1:1 and the width of the image view to 50. But for iphone 5 and 5s this size is too big as I feel. So how can I change the size of the `UIImageView` relative to the screen width.
Please help me.
Thanks

**This is my current view**

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: you need to first set width and then set aspect ratio. Width is related to screen width, i mean to say make use of multiplier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least 2 ways you could configure image size based on the screen size:

- [Size-Classes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Size-ClassSpecificLayout.html) allows you to set different width constraint value based on Trait Variation: Compact or Regular. Just select the width constraint, click on the Plus button on the left of it's Constant value and add a new variation for the iPhone device screens. [image: Regular width trait variation constraint]
- Manual approach with Aspect Ration constraint. This way you should select both ImageView and cell's ContentView, create "Equal Width" constraint and change it's multiplier value. Start with a 1:5 value - looking good. [image: Proportional width constraint]

Comment: Do I need to set width constraint as well for the image view?

Comment: for the Manual approach

Comment: @user1960169, not for the manual approach - your ImageView will already have a width constraint. The only difference here this constraint binds two views width instead of binding imageView's width to a constant value.

Comment: But its covering my whole cell,, even tho I set the multiplier 0.25 :(

Comment: I updated the question with my previous constraints. This is all good but just not changing the size according to the screen width. Which constraint I need to remove?

Comment: @user1960169, if you selected ContentView first and your ImageView next, then you created constraint with reversed dependency. It means you have to set multiplier not 0.25, but to 4. Also you other constraints could influence on the result.

Comment: @user1960169, it's hard to tell which constraint should be removed. I even don't see a Proportional Width constraint in your list.